# Does Amazon RDS with Multi-AZ have automatic failover ability?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, failover

I would like to setup a PostgreSQL database with read-only standby with automatic failover ability.

Does Amazon RDS with Multi-AZ have automatic failover ability?

If yes, will the endpoint/DNS automatically point to the new standby database?

Comment: There's a video "Deep dive on Amazon RDS Multi-AZ with two readable standbys" that covers how this works for both the "one failover" and "two readable failover" options. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fLqJXTOhUg4

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 scenarios to this question as it was little ambiguous in the question.

**scenario 1** :- *rds with multi AZ.*

- Here standby instance will have automatic failover.
- Here the endpoint/DNS automatically point to the new standby database, no manual intervention is needed.
- But read and write is being taken by only the master DB and sync replication takes with standby database.

**scenario 2** :- *rds with multi AZ where read replicas is also there.*

- In this scenario read replicas are not treated like standby database database by default.howver they can be used like standby.
- failover is not automatic.
- You will need to manually update your dns.

[article from aws says](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/01/amazon-rds-read-replicas-now-support-multi-az-deployments/#:%7E:text=Combining%20Read%20Replicas%20with%20Multi,in%20a%20different%20AWS%20Region.)

> A Read Replica in a different region than the source database can be used as a standby database and promoted to become the new production database in case of a regional disruption.

also a similar question on stack should also help you [Difference between "Multi-AZ Deployment" and "Read Replica Verison Multi-AZ Deployment"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58779115/13126651)

Answer (score 0):

Scenario 2 seems to have slightly evolved since 2021.
Now this has become [Multi-AZ DB Cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/multi-az-db-clusters-concepts.html)

> Reader DB instances act as automatic failover targets and also serve
> read traffic to increase application read throughput. If an outage
> occurs on your writer DB instance, RDS manages failover to one of the
> reader DB instances. RDS does this based on which reader DB instance
> has the most recent change record.