# How to differentiate between a multi-az read replica and the a read replica?

Tags: amazon-aurora

How to differantiate between a read replica and a multi-az replica? Is there an option, where i can see the difference in AWS?

I read this, but could not find the difference:
[Difference between "Multi-AZ Deployment" and "Read Replica Verison Multi-AZ Deployment"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58779115/difference-between-multi-az-deployment-and-read-replica-verison-multi-az-depl)

Comment: In the Amazon RDS console, when you select a specific DB instance, its details page will show if it's Multi-AZ or not. If "Multi-AZ Deployment" is set to "Yes", then it's a Multi-AZ DB instance.

Comment: @PiyushPatil Where exacly, there is no details page.

Answer (score 0):

Go to RDS console -> Databases. The rightmost column will indicate Multi-AZ.

[image]